# Unity 4.2 Android In-App Billing: Signature verification failed

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, in-app-billing, prime31

I am testing an App in Unity using a prime[31] plugin in which the user is able to purchase sounds. If a sound button is clicked, a .cs file `PurchasableSound` is called which determines if the sound has been purchased or not. (FYI it tries to do so using `PlayerPrefs.GetInt`, however, I haven't managed to get it to work).
If the sound has not yet been purchased, I call another .cs file, `PurchaseSounds`, which activates a panel in unity in which the user can choose to buy either 4 or 10 of all purchasable sounds. In that piece of code, `GoogleIAB.init(key)` and `GoogleIAB.queryInventory(skus)` are executed and the one of the two products mentioned above can be purchased.

However, during execution of the entire scene on my Android device, the `Signature verification` fails:

```
    09-06 18:10:08.998: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:08.998: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:09.008: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:09.008: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:09.008: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536): PurchasableSound has been called.
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536): PurchasableSound has been called.
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536): PurchasableSound has been called.
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:09.028: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:09.339: I/Unity(10536): billingSupportedEvent
09-06 18:10:09.339: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:09.339: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:09.359: I/Unity(10536): queryInventoryFailedEvent: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)
09-06 18:10:09.359: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:09.359: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:11.181: D/dalvikvm(6337): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 46% free 3096K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 54ms
09-06 18:10:11.881: E/NativeActivity(10536): channel '4068a288 com.gumasd.beta/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (client)' ~ Failed to receive dispatch signal.  status=-11
09-06 18:10:12.212: E/NativeActivity(10536): channel '4068a288 com.gumasd.beta/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (client)' ~ Failed to receive dispatch signal.  status=-11
09-06 18:10:12.222: E/NativeActivity(10536): channel '4068a288 com.gumasd.beta/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (client)' ~ Failed to receive dispatch signal.  status=-11
09-06 18:10:12.232: I/Unity(10536): PurchasableSound: Click
09-06 18:10:12.232: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:12.232: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:12.232: I/Unity(10536): PurchasableSound: Sound has not yet been purchased.
09-06 18:10:12.232: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:12.232: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:12.282: I/Unity(10536): PurchaseSounds has been called.
09-06 18:10:12.282: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:12.282: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:12.282: I/keystore(1255): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
09-06 18:10:12.292: D/Finsky(3418): [32] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.gumasd.beta: Account from first account - [1sBSp5jt9jfvUfoG2wXSTiotEok]
09-06 18:10:12.292: I/Unity(10536): GoogleIAB: init was called.
09-06 18:10:12.292: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:12.292: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:12.292: I/Unity(10536): GoogleIAB: queryInventory was called.
09-06 18:10:12.292: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:12.292: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:12.302: D/Finsky(3418): [36] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.gumasd.beta: Account from first account - [1sBSp5jt9jfvUfoG2wXSTiotEok]
09-06 18:10:12.312: D/Finsky(3418): [37] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.gumasd.beta: Account from first account - [1sBSp5jt9jfvUfoG2wXSTiotEok]
09-06 18:10:12.322: D/Finsky(3418): [37] InAppBillingUtils.getPreferredAccount: com.gumasd.beta: Account from first account - [1sBSp5jt9jfvUfoG2wXSTiotEok]
09-06 18:10:12.332: I/Unity(10536): billingSupportedEvent
09-06 18:10:12.332: I/Unity(10536):  
09-06 18:10:12.332: I/Unity(10536): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
09-06 18:10:12.352: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.352: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.352: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.372: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.372: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.372: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.382: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.382: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.382: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.412: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.412: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.412: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.432: D/dalvikvm(10536): GC_CONCURRENT freed 262K, 46% free 3072K/5639K, external 2K/514K, paused 3ms+4ms
09-06 18:10:12.432: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.432: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.432: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.442: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.442: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.442: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.452: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.452: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.452: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.452: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:12.452: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
09-06 18:10:12.452: W/Prime31-IABH(10536): In-app billing warning: Purchase signature verification **FAILED**. Not adding item.
09-06 18:10:12.462: I/Unity(10536): queryInventoryFailedEvent: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)
```

I don't understand why this happens. I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the Base64 License Key I added. Based on `09-06 18:10:12.332: I/Unity(10536): billingSupportedEvent`, GoogleIAB initializes, but from `queryInventoryFailedEvent: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)` it's clear that my skus can't be fetched. What's going wrong and why? Does this have to do with keystore or key settings in Unity that were filled erroneously?

Comment: We were beta testing MobiShop (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636) on our project and had a similar issue however that was resolved when we uploaded a alpha build to Google Developer Console. You cannot test the purchases before then and you must assign a test user to test it.

Answer (score 0):

1 . I noticed

```
09-06 18:10:09.008: E/Prime31-SEC(10536): Signature verification failed.
09-06 18:10:09.008: W/Prime31-SEC(10536): signature does not match data.
```

So,I guess your public key is wrong, try to check your public Key. You can add some log in android code. I didn't use  prime[31] before, but I guess there's a

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, GoogleBase64PublicKey);
```

code which is offered by google should be called. You can logout the key before it.

2 . make sure your sku spells right .Moreover, You should make the items be published

3 . You can find a open source project [**here**](https://github.com/fansongy/UIAP/tree/master/Client/Assets/Plugins/Android) which I wrote several days before, maybe it can be of some help.